# How can I use sub-domain as parameter in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, subdomain

When I access to http://testuser.example.com,
I'd like it to access to 'user' controller's 'show' action with the parameter 'testuser', which is user name in user Model.

How can I archive this easily??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
@user = User.find_by_name(request.subdomain)
```

**update**

for routes

```
constraints(:subdomain => /.+/) do
  root :to => 'user#show'
end
```

simply you define new routing rules when subdomain exists, you can change it according to your needs.

Comment: what about routes.rb? nothing to do with it?